# How does kotlin use this by delegate to instantiate the viewmodel

Tags: android, kotlin

I was reading through the google android architecture example and came across this.Can someone explain to me how this delegate works?

```
private val viewModel by viewModels<TasksViewModel> { getViewModelFactory() }
```

where getViewModelFactory is an extension method that returns a ViewModelFactory and TasksViewModel is an instance of ViewModel()

The way that I read this is similar to:

```
private val viewModel: TasksViewModel by Fragment.ViewModel(ViewModelFactory)
```

can someone elaborate on if my understanding is correct.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

`by viewModels(...)` is part of [`fragment-ktx`](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx#fragment) library, it's a convienience short hand for creating a `lazy` delegate obtaining `ViewModels`.

```
// creates lazy delegate for obtaining zero-argument MyViewModel
private val viewModel : MyViewModel by viewModels()
// it's functionally equal to:
private val viewModel by lazy {
    ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
}

// with factory:
private val viewModel : MyViewModel by viewModels { getViewModelFactory() }
// is equal to:
private val viewModel by lazy {
    ViewModelProvider(this, getViewModelFactory()).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
}
```

Comment: thanks, keep in mind that viewModel instance must be defined as immutable val

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi and if this viewmodel is used and instantiated in 2 fragment classes one beong main and the other is dialog and it used 2 different classes.